# Not able to apply CMK encryption to Azure Storage Account through ARM Template

Tags: encryption, azure-storage, azure-rm-template, azure-files, azure-storage-account

I am trying to attach CMK Encryption with Azure Storage Account through ARM Template but I am getting error as below. Need quick help with it. Able to apply it through portal after Storage Account is created but not able to do via ARM Template  while creating Storage Account.

Error- [error]FeatureNotSupportedForAccount: Missing pre-requisites to enable EncryptionAtRest/Customer Managed Key for this storage account.

ARM:-

```
"resources": [
{​​​​​​​
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
  "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
  "name": "[variables('storageaccountname')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "sku": {​​​​​​​
    "name": "[parameters('storageaccountype')]"
  }​​​​​​​,
  "kind": "[parameters('storagekind')]",
  "properties": {​​​​​​​
    "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
    "accesstier": "[parameters('accesstier')]",
    "largeFileSharesState": "[parameters('largefilesharesstate')]",
    "allowBlobPublicAccess": false,
    "encryption": {​​​​​​​
      "services": {​​​​​​​
        "file": {​​​​​​​
          "enabled": true
        }​​​​​​​,
        "blob": {​​​​​​​
          "enabled": true
        }​​​​​​​
      }​​​​​​​,
      "keySource": "Microsoft.Keyvault",
      "keyvaultproperties": {​​​​​​​
        "keyvaulturi": "[parameters('kvuri')]",
        "keyname": "[parameters('keyname')]",
        "keyversion": "[parameters('keyversion')]"
      }​​​​​​​
    }​​​​​​​
  }​​​​​​​,
  "tags": {​​​​​​​
    "abcid": "[parameters('abcid')]"
  }​​​​​​​
}​​​​​​​
```

Comment: please try to use `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryptionScopes`.

Comment: Thank you but please explain a bit more :)

Comment: Hi. I made a mistake. According to the error,  it seems that you have not registered the feature. Could you please check it? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/account-encryption-key-create?tabs=template#register-to-use-the-account-encryption-key

Comment: yes, I had a look at that link. But is it mandatory to register before automating it as if doing manually on SA, it is not required. Is it so ? More so, the link explains about Table & Queue. What about Blob & File ? Is registering required ?

Comment: No. If you want to use the feature, we must do that. Azure blob and File should not do that. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption#about-encryption-key-management

Comment: ok, that is fine for Table & Queue. But the original error I posted was for File & Blob only. And I need CMK encryption for File & Blob. I can skip it for Table & Queue.

Comment: ok. I will do a test

Comment: thanks a lot :) yiu can check via ARM. I got it working via PS script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/customer-managed-keys-configure-key-vault?tabs=portal#configure-a-key-vault), if you want to configure encryption with customer-managed keys stored in Azure key valt, we need to do the following steps

1. Create  storage  account and Enable Identity
2. Update Azure Key vault. Enable soft delete and purge protection.
3. Configure access policy for the storage  account's Identity
4. Configure customer-managed keys for the storage account.

Regarding how to configure these with arm template, please refer to the following template

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "keyName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "keyVersion": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "vaultName": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        },
        "accountNmae": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "tetsdfgfgdffd"
        },
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [{
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "kind": "Storage",
            "name": "[ parameters('accountNmae')]",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "location": "[ parameters('location')]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }, {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
            "name": "[parameters('vaultName')]",
            "location": "eastasia",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('accountNmae'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "family": "A",
                    "name": "Standard"
                },
                "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantid]",
                "accessPolicies": [],
                "enabledForDeployment": true,
                "enabledForDiskEncryption": true,
                "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
                "enableSoftDelete": true
            }
        }, {

            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "name": "updateStorageAccount",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaultName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "0.1.0.0",
                    "resources": [{
                            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/add')]",
                            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
                            "properties": {
                                "accessPolicies": [{
                                        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantid]",
                                        "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',  parameters('accountNmae')),'2019-06-01', 'full').identity.principalId]",
                                        "permissions": {
                                            "keys": [
                                                "wrapkey",
                                                "unwrapkey",
                                                "get"
                                            ],
                                            "secrets": [],
                                            "certificates": []
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }, {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                            "sku": {
                                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                                "tier": "Standard"
                            },
                            "kind": "Storage",
                            "name": "[parameters('accountNmae')]",
                            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "identity": {
                                "type": "SystemAssigned"
                            },
                            "properties": {
                                "encryption": {
                                    "services": {
                                        "file": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                        },
                                        "blob": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Keyvault",
                                    "keyvaultproperties": {
                                        "keyvaulturi": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults',parameters('vaultName')),'2016-10-01', 'full').properties.vaultUri]",
                                        "keyname": "[parameters('keyName')]",
                                        "keyversion": "[parameters('keyversion')]"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies', parameters('vaultName'), 'add')]"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://www.codeisahighway.com/how-to-use-customer-managed-keys-with-azure-key-vault-and-azure-storage-encryption-using-arm-template/)

Comment: yes, its true..almost did the same through PS. I had KV, Keys beforehand.

Comment: @Chaitanya Do you have any other concerns? If you have no, could you please accept it as an answer?

Comment: but why was I getting that original error message is still not known to me...the blog I had referred yesterday, it asks to run the ARM twice whereas I need to have all in the first run only..

Comment: @Chaitanya Regarding the error, in the arm template, we cannot enable identity in storage  and configure access policy fro the identity. We need to enable  identity   configure access policy then we can enable cmk in template.

Comment: @JimXu is the key version a mandatory parameter in the keyvault properties of ARM template can I hardcode it to the latest version of the key in the template. I have tried to remove the version and run it throws an error.